# Fiddler not capturing some connections

Tags: proxy, network-programming, fiddler, http-proxy

I'm trying to use Fiddler version 5.0.20202.18177 (latest as of writing) to determine the URLs used by various online / web installers.

This works fine in most cases. For example, with `SpotifySetup.exe`:

[image]

However, this does not work in some cases. For example, with [`DropboxInstaller.exe`](https://www.dropbox.com/en_GB/downloading) and [`bitdefender_online.exe`](https://www.bitdefender.co.uk/solutions/free/thank-you.html):

[image]

[image]

I have ensured that:

1. HTTPS decryption is set up for all processes:
   [image]
2. All types of connections are being captured:
   [image]
3. Windows' proxies are set as expected.

   [image]
4. All Windows 10 AppContainer Loopback exemptions are in place:
   [image]

Running Fiddler as administrator doesn't make a difference.

I would have guessed that the executables simply aren't utilising the proxy but, as far as I'm aware, if the proxy is set at the Windows level then they can't override that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my discussion with Robert, I ended up abandoning Fiddler, setting up a VirtualBox VM running [pfSense Community Edition](https://www.pfsense.org/download/?section=downloads) (free) + [Squid3 with HTTPS Interception](https://turbofuture.com/internet/Intercepting-HTTPS-Traffic-Using-the-Squid-Proxy-in-pfSense) and Access Logging, installing the pfSense's root CA certificate in my test Windows VM, and changing my test Windows VM's default gateway to the LAN IP address of the pfSense which worked.

In the case of the Dropbox example, it was initially logging `TCP_TUNNEL_ABORTED/200    client.dropbox.com:443` so I added `client.dropbox.com` to the whitelist in the ACLs then it worked and I could see the full EXE URL:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A program can use of the proxy defined in the Windows Internet settings but it also can ignore those settings and directly connect to the Internet.

The proxy settings are only used automatically for programs that use an HTTP client provided by Microsoft (e.g. WinHTTP for C/C++ or a Dot.net Http client implementation). 
All other programs that use their own HTTP client can query the Windows proxy settings and apply them but this is optionally. From a Windows perspective those programs just open TCP connections, what protocol is used on the connection is unknown to Windows hence Windows could not enforce that a proxy is used even if it would try to do so.

By default even programs that come with Windows like the command-line too curl ignore the Windows proxy settings.

Dropbox for example has their own proxy settings within the Dropbox client. There you have to configure Fiddler as proxy.

Bitdefender also seem to have [it's own proxy settings](https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/2645/) where you have to configure Fiddler.

Comment: Hmm. I thought it'd be something like that. Would something like Wireshark capture all HTTP connections regardless of whether the apps utilise proxies?

Yes, the applications themselves have options for proxies but the installers don't seem to.

Comment: @mythofechelon Wireshark is able to capture all connections and all data, with npcap even localhost connections can be captured with Wireshark. But in difference to Fiddler HTTPS decryption only works for servers you have the private key or where you can extract the session key from the client application when the SSL/TLS connection is established.

Comment: Yes, I've just been experimenting with Wireshark and it seems that, without the private keys, it can only decrypt SSL/TLS connections via `SSLKEYLOGFILE` but that requires the applications to explicitly use it which hardly any do. Do you have any recommendations for me to accomplish what I want? Perhaps a gateway-level proxy or something?

Comment: @mythofechelon Nothing simple. You can try a separate Linux PC running Mitmproxy in transparent mode https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/#transparent-proxy Or you try to generate `SSLKEYLOGFILE` using Frida attaching to the updater process and extracting the session keys (this would be quite some work and has to be adapted for ever program).